# iOS RestKit - getting 26 warnings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, warnings, restkit

I am having a go at using RestKit by following this tutorial - [RestKit Tutorial - Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial).

Everything seems to go as it should, however I am getting 26 warnings (no errors, so it does compile). Now I have done exactly what the tutorial says, so i can't explain any of them. They are in the RestKit FrameWork (the little white house logo)

Any idea how I can resolve these? I have redone the exercise several times, but they always come up. They don't come up in the sample project.

Any help would be great. Also all the warnings seems to be different, so I am not sure what I need to post for code, because that could be the whole framework???

I have added an image of the warnings that bug me the most. I would like to have these cleared.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by chance using a beta version of xCode and/or targeting iOS SDK 6.0? I've noticed this on a project too, with xCode 4.5, targeting iOS SDK 6.0. The odd thing is that if I pull the project down on my laptop with xCode 4.3, targeting iOS SDK 5.1 there are **zero** warnings. I resorted to ignoring the RestKit warnings on my main machine.

Comment: I have tried both the a beta and 4.4.1 from the app store in completely separate projects and builds. I don't have 4.3 but I may just have ignore them - it is just annoying:-)

Comment: Agreed! Did you add RestKit using git submodule or download the source zip? I just found this bug report + fix (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/884). Looks like they've patched the warnings in master, but I doubt those patches have made it to the download on restkit.org yet. If you added the submodule try pulling the latest version.

Comment: I just downloaded the master and used that and it did the trick:-) it is down from 26 warnings to 4. Thanks for that tip:-)

Answer (score 0):

I would just ignore or attempt to fix them. Warnings, while important, arent the biggest deal in the world, and if they are in a framework as common as RestKit, then assume that the code works and move on with your day.

Comment: Yeah fair comment, I am just puzzled why they come up in my build and not in the example - even after the resetting and removing any builds

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the exact same thing happened to me. It was 23 warnings, however. They were caused with incompatibilities between Xcode 4.3 and Xcode 4.4.1. The 0.10.1 version had a lot of warnings in 4.4.1 whereas in 4.3 it was building fine. The update to 0.10.2 fixed these problems and was available in the git master branch, but it wasn't posted to website ([http://reskit.org](http://restkit.rg)) where I had downloaded it. Updating to 0.10.2 fixed the warnings for me.